# How to route via code in an Angular hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router, angular-hybrid

I'm working on a Hybrid Angular/AngularJS app.
The main AppModule is Angular module that uses AppRoutingModule that uses a given state. Something like that:

AppModule:

`imports: [AModule, BModule, AppRoutingModule, ...]`

AppRoutingModule:

`imports: [UIRouterUpgradeModule.forRoot(states: some_state)]`

States:

```
export const some_state: [
  {
    name: 'a',
    url: '/a'
    views: {
            main: {component: AComponent}
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    url: '/b'
    views: {
            main: {component: BComponent}
    }
  }
]
```

What I want to do - say I'm in a BComponent, I want to navigate to AComponent.
In a pure angular component I would use the Router from the RouterModule (forRoot in AppModule and forChild in child modules).
Something like router.navigateToURL('...')

Now I'm using UIRouterUpgradeModule and I could not find how to do it.
Any help will be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your component, first declare `router` in constructor like shown below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  // ...
}
```

Then create a function that will be used whenever route change is required, you can bind this function to any event like button click to see required changes :

```
changeRoute() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/b');
}
```

Comment: This wont work since I'm using the UIRouterUpgradeModule with states that are fitting for a hybrid solution. The Regular router requires a different states in the form of a Routers array.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing that worked for me is this:
Imported the StateService from @uirouter/core in the constructor like so:

`constructor(private stateService: StateService)`

and in my method did the following:

`stateService.go('URL_TO_GO_TO');`

This worked for me and I was redirected as wanted.